# Ubuntu tells me my init.d Service of spring boot application not found and can not to run it

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu

I have followed spring boot deployment for Installation as an init.d Service (System V)
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-install

my actions are as follow:

```
sudo ln -s /home/centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

and to sart:

```
service centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start
```

I get an error:

```
Failed to start centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.service: Unit centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.service not found.
```

Is there any operations I forget?

Comment: Assuming that you followed the doc step by step, you may want to check permissions.

Comment: @z atef    Yeah,I have followd every steps, and used the command of sudo /etc/init.d/centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start as an alternative to start.I also got an error which tells me sudo: /etc/init.d/centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the command of sudo chmod +x /etc/inti.d/appname and used command of sudo /etc/init.d/appname start. It works.

Comment: but it doesn't explain why `service name start` not work.